# how can we upload all kind of file at server?

Tags: java, file, upload

```
       <%@ page import="java.io.*" %>
<%
```

String contentType = request.getContentType();

if ((contentType != null) && (contentType.indexOf("multipart/form-data") >= 0))     {
    DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(request.getInputStream());

```
int formDataLength = request.getContentLength();
byte dataBytes[] = new byte[formDataLength];
int byteRead = 0;
int totalBytesRead = 0;

while (totalBytesRead < formDataLength) 
{
    byteRead = in.read(dataBytes, totalBytesRead, formDataLength);
    totalBytesRead += byteRead;
}

String file = new String(dataBytes);

String saveFile = file.substring(file.indexOf("filename=\"") + 10);
saveFile = saveFile.substring(0, saveFile.indexOf("\n"));
saveFile = saveFile.substring(saveFile.lastIndexOf("\\")+1,saveFile.indexOf("\""));
int lastIndex = contentType.lastIndexOf("=");
String boundary = contentType.substring(lastIndex +1,contentType.length());
int pos;

pos = file.indexOf("filename=\"");
pos = file.indexOf("\n", pos) + 1;
pos = file.indexOf("\n", pos) + 1;
pos = file.indexOf("\n", pos) + 1;
int boundaryLocation = file.indexOf(boundary, pos) - 4;
int startPos = ((file.substring(0, pos)).getBytes()).length;
int endPos = ((file.substring(0, boundaryLocation))
.getBytes()).length;
saveFile="http://hpws1/shared_mxd/pdf/" + saveFile;

FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(saveFile);
fileOut.write(dataBytes, startPos, (endPos - startPos));
fileOut.flush();
fileOut.close();

%><Br><table border="2"><tr><td><b>You have successfully
```

upload the file by the name of: <% out.println(saveFil

Comment: Avoid scriptlets at all costs.

Comment: What @SotiriosDelimanolis said. More on subject [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files).

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing with that scriptlet is no longer acceptable. You can try to use a [servlet and form](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/glraq.html) to do your upload instead.